# Lambidify throws TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' when I try to plot through Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime-error, sympy

Whenever I try to run this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np 
from numpy import * 
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x,y
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot

def Plot_2D_RHS(xdata,ydata,RHS):
    x = symbols('x')
    RHS=sympy.sympify(RHS)
    RHS=sympy.lambdify([x], RHS)
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
    plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, label='Data')
    plt.plot(xdata, RHS(xdata), label='Fit')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

xdata=[1, 4 , 6, 8 ,9,10]
ydata=[2, 5, 7, 8,11,12]
RHS='9.8+3.7*x'
Plot_2D_RHS(xdata,ydata,RHS)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Essam\Source\Repos\Curve-Fitting\NetwonWillRemember\Trail1\Trail1.py", line 182, in <module>
    Plot_2D_RHS(xdata,ydata,RHS)
  File "C:\Users\Essam\Source\Repos\Curve-Fitting\NetwonWillRemember\Trail1\Trail1.py", line 16, in Plot_2D_RHS
    plt.plot(xdata, RHS(xdata), label='Fit')
  File "<lambdifygenerated-1>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

and no plot is shown, however for some reason if we change the x in the RHS to something like 'cos(x)' it works with no problems, how can I solve this issue without using Sympy's plot since it doesn't offer scatter plots.

Comment: start by making `xdata` and `ydata` arrays, rather than lists.  A list is a `sequence` that doesn't implement multiplication.

Comment: Worked like magic, would you mind writing this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [23]: sympify('9.8+3.7*x')                                                                          
Out[23]: 3.7⋅x + 9.8

In [24]: f=lambdify([x],sympify('9.8+3.7*x'))                                                          

In [25]: print(f.__doc__)                                                                              
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x)

Expression:

3.7*x + 9.8

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return (3.7*x + 9.8)


Imported modules:
```

It works fine with an array argument, but not with a list:

```
In [26]: f(np.arange(3))                                                                               
Out[26]: array([ 9.8, 13.5, 17.2])

In [27]: f([1,2,3])                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-816cce84b257> in <module>
----> 1 f([1,2,3])

<lambdifygenerated-2> in _lambdifygenerated(x)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(x):
----> 2     return (3.7*x + 9.8)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```